# How to use jQuery Deferred/Promise with a second $.ajax() after a timeout

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have an event handler binded to `$someEl` that should only execute when `oRes` is populated with data, which can come from either the primary source (`getData1()`) or the backup source (`getData2()`). Data is requested from the backup source only if the primary source times out.

If the primary source does not time out, then everything works; however, when the backup `getData2()` function is called, `dfd` is never resolved, so nothing ever logs when I click on `$someEl`. I suspect it's not working because the Deferred object in `getData2()` is overwriting the `dfd` variable that the `$someEl` click handler is referring to.

I have a feeling I'm not applying Deferred/Promise using a "best practice" pattern. Given this scenario, how would you make the click handler properly wait for oRes to be populated from either a primary AJAX response or a secondary AJAX response after a timeout?

Some notes for clarification:

- `getData1()` has to be executed only after the document is ready
- `$someEl.click()` may fire anytime during the document's loading, so the event handler needs to be defined outside of `$(document).ready()`
- I'm stuck with jQuery 1.7.1

Here is the code:

```js
var oRes, dfd;

// Get data from primary source
function getData1() {
  dfd = $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
      oRes = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (textStatus==='timeout') getData2();
    },
    timeout: 10000 // 10-second timeout
  });
}

// Get data from backup source
function getData2() {
  dfd = $.ajax({...});
}

$someEl.click(function() {
  dfd.done(function() {
    console.log('This should only log when oRes is ready');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  getData1();
});
```

I've simulated my situation in this pen: http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/pyVyKj

Essentially, I'm having trouble getting the event handler to output "Data is ready!" when `oRes` is populated without having to manually click on the box after the page is loaded.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that with your current strategy, every time $someEl is clicked it will bind another callback to the deferred object, so when the deferred is finally resolved it will run your callback X times, where X is the number of times the element was clicked. This could be your desired behavior, but just wanted to make sure you were aware.

Comment: @MattDiamond thanks for pointing that out, very good point :). I have changed the code to use `.one('click', ...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to bring it up one level.

Create a Deferred up-front that your click handler will listen to (and that instance won't change).

You then resolve that deferred from either `getData1()` or `getData2()`:

```
var oRes,

    // Resolve this deferred when data has been successfully loaded:
    dfd = $.Deferred(),

     // But add listeners to this promise:
    dfdPromise = dfd.promise();

// Get data from primary source
function getData1() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            oRes = data;

            // Resolve when data loaded:
            dfd.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (textStatus==='timeout') getData2();
        },
        timeout: 10000 // 10-second timeout
    });
}

// Get data from backup source
function getData2() {
    $.ajax({...})
        .then(function(data){
            // Fallback data resolve:
            dfd.resolve(data);
        });
}

$someEl.click(function() {
    dfdPromise.done(function() {
        console.log('This should only log when oRes is ready');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData1();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sly_cardinal, your solution worked. This was the mental hump I needed to get over :-). Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/zqjBvp

Answer (score 0):

I would include the function call within the callbacks of the ajax request.

```
var oRes = null;
var dfd = null;

// Get data from backup source
function getData2() {
  dfd = $.ajax({...});
}

// Get the primary data source
function getData1() {
  dfd = $.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        oRes = data;

        // set the click handler when oRes is successfully set
        $(someEl).click(function() {
            console.log('This should only log when oRes is ready');
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (textStatus==='timeout') getData2();
    },
    always: function(){
        if (oRes==null){
            getData2();
        }
    }
    timeout: 10000 // 10-second timeout
  });
}
```

Comment: I would love to do that, unfortunately I'm working with code that's part of a larger app where $someEl *may* be clicked before `$(document).ready`, so its event handler must be defined outside of it (and hence outside of `getData1()`). I'll edit the question to add clarity.

Comment: That won't be a problem because the click event is assigned after the javascript is loaded.  If the DOM hasn't finished and the user clicks, then they will most likely try again once they see everything has loaded.

Comment: chriswirz, I've simulated my situation in this pen: http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/pyVyKj -- the crux of the problem is that I need to trigger a click on the box in the initial load, but the promise is not honored or something else is blocking the initial logging. What I want to happen is that when oData is populated the event handler message should say "Data is ready!" without having to manually click on the box.